# Why the collection of background/negative image dataset is not taught in object detection tutorials and books?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, agi

While I was doing an object detection project, I have encountered the problem of getting FALSE POSITIVES and FALSE NEGATIVES. After days of research on StackOverflow, I figured out that I need to collect more negative images or background images.I decided to document this process so other people could easily solve this issue and the result of documentation is [this](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/what-is-not-taught-in-object-detection-tutorials-and-books-dc33ab4c3063?source=friends_link&sk=9b8d66fb525ccafa19e838105d2ce329). After training the model with Negative/Background images, my FP/FN rates were normalized so that in video frames I started getting fewer FPs. All of us, machine learning developers get experience by getting hands dirty - this is clear to all of us. But I haven't seen(probably missed) any video tutorials or examples on books showing how to collect background images and why we need them at all.

So here is the question: Okay, so every experienced ML engineer knows what is the FP/FNs are, and their prevention methods. But why this topic is less known and taught within popular object detection tutorials and books? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Normally you select from the background image.

Comment: @FourierFlux what does that mean?